# Modification of Bubblesort program with user input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have created a program previously using the *BubbleSort* method that works to sort numbers in a list that already exists, however, I am having difficulty with trying to manipulate this program in order to allow a user to input the list of numbers to be sorted instead. So far I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MedianValue {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //use scanner to input list of numbers to sort

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numbers = new int[] {scan.nextInt()};


    //nested for loop
    //outer loop just iterating
        //inner loop going through and flipping
            //checking if out of order (if statement)


    int counter = 0;

    //outer loop: keep doing this until it's sorted

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i = i + 1)

    //put in a inner loop number.length times minus one because we don't want to swap the last element

        for(counter = 0; counter < numbers.length - 1; counter = counter + 1)
        {



            if (numbers [counter] > numbers [counter + 1])
            {


                int temporary = numbers [counter];
                numbers [counter] = numbers [counter + 1];
                numbers [counter + 1] = temporary;
            }
        }


        for(int i =0; i < numbers.length; i = i + 1)
        {
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

But, in this program, instead of sorting the inputted numbers, the program simply prints the first number that is inputted by the user.  I am not sure if I need to move where my scanner function is placed, or add on to it within the loop for it to sort all of the numbers as I want it to do.  I am lost on where to change the program if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `int[] numbers = new int[] {scan.nextInt()};` is a single assigment. scan read a single input and assign to number[0].

You actually need to modify your code for `scan` to read `n` numbers and store in n-sized `numbers`.

something like.

```
int[] numbers = new int[scan.nextInt()];
for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
   numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `int[] numbers = new int[] {scan.nextInt()};` will always create an array (not a List) of size 1.

Usually in these kinds of assignments you get `n + 1` numbers, for example `5 3 6 2 4 1` would mean "I'm going to give you five numbers. Oh here they are: 3 6 2 4 and 1!"

You probably want something like `int[] numbers = new int[scan.nextInt()];` - then loop from `0` to `numbers.length` to fill the array.